# Jasper Reports - Print all reports to one sheet in excel export

Tags: java, jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I'm using Jasper with spring to export a set of separated reports to an excel file via a list of JasperPrint using the following code:

```
    public File getExcelFile() throws IOException, JRException{
    File excel = new File(getReportTitle()+".xlsx");
    JRXlsxExporter exporter = new JRXlsxExporter();
    exporter.setExporterInput(SimpleExporterInput.getInstance(jasperPrintList)); // where jasperPrintList is a List<JasperPrint> of separated reports.
    exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(excel));
    SimpleXlsxReportConfiguration reportConfig = new SimpleXlsxReportConfiguration();
    reportConfig.setOnePagePerSheet(false);
    reportConfig.setWrapText(true);
    reportConfig.setAutoFitPageHeight(true);
    exporter.setConfiguration(reportConfig);
    exporter.exportReport();
    return excel;
}
```

Above code generates excel file with one sheet per report.

How can I set it to generate all reports to one sheet only, not sheet per report?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicates: [jasper excel report how to merge multiple templates on one excell sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33411448/876298). Petter gavve the answer at comments

Comment: Another one: [jasperreports how to export multiple jrmxl files to a single worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14882722/876298)